# How to test functions inside functional components with React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a functional component which uses useState hook as shown below:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
    export const PList = (props) =>{
      const [obj, setObj]= useState({
        value: null,
       open: null
      });
      let onDeleteList = (data) =>{
        setObj({....});
      };
      return(
        <React.Fragment>
            { 
                props.arr.map((p,i)=>{
                    return <childA onDeleteList={onDeleteList} />
                })
            }
         </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
```

I an using Jest+ enzyme and looking to write a test case to test the onDeleteList function in this component. I have tried with the below code:

```
describe('PList',()=>{
   let wrapper = shallow(<Plist {...props}/>);
   it('should call onDeleteList',()=>{
      expect(wrapper.find('onDeleteList')).toBeTruthy();
   });
 });
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way, the coverage report still shows the onDeleteList() is not covered in the test case. Can anyone please advise how can I write a test case for this scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing React Functional Component with Hooks using Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713644/testing-react-functional-component-with-hooks-using-jest)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should be testing:

```
import childA here 

describe('PList',()=>{
   let wrapper = shallow(<Plist {...props}/>);
   it('should call onDeleteList',()=>{
      const onDeleteListHandler=wrapper.find(childA).at(0).prop("onDeleteList");
    onDeleteListhandler(pass your data here);
     expect(onDeleteListhandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    

   });
   
 });
```

Comment: Thank you Sakshi..! But when I ran this code it had thrown an error on the wrapper,find statement at 'prop' saying "Method props is meant to run on 1 node. 0 found instead. Probably, this is because the <childA> is being returned from an arr.map(). Sorry I missed that, I have now updated the code in the question. Can you please advise further?

Comment: In your test case what value are you providing to your `props` ?

Comment: I am passing an array with some static data: arr= ["node1", "node2"]

Comment: Show your complete props structure that you are having in your test case

Comment: const props = { 
      arr: ["node1",node2"]
}

Comment: it should be like this: const props={arr:["node1","node2"]}

Comment: Yes, I did pass the props as above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227072/discussion-between-sakshi-and-raghu).